# If I aimed two identical lasers at a screen, what would the interference pattern look like?

Tags: laser, interference

If I aimed two identical lasers at a distant screen, what would the interference pattern look like? Could this be modelled as a wavefront passing through two slits, i.e. the double slit experiment?

I want to simulate the interference of two identical laser beams and be able to vary the laser separation, distance to screen, wavelength etc and model the corresponding change in interference pattern.

Comment: It depends on a lot of things. If the lasers are operating independently of each other, there would be a very quickly fluctuating interference effect that would not be "visible", except with exceptionally high time resolution equipment. If the lasers were mode locked, there would be a (potentially even visible) slowly changing interference pattern. This is not so much an experiment resembling the double slit experiment, but one that is about beating frequencies between oscillators.

Comment: this is what you need http://phet.colorado.edu/en/simulation/legacy/wave-interference